# Set Ctrl+Alt+T to open a maximized terminal

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut to open a terminal, but I cannot see how I can get it maximized. When I start it manually, I can simply do a `gnome-terminal --maximize`, but that does not apply for the shortcut. Even a changing of the .desktop files did not change anything.

Any way to let the shortcut open a maximized terminal window?

I use regular Gnome 2 on Ubuntu 11.04 with no compositing effects.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In `gconf-editor` set the key

```
/apps/compiz-1/plugins/gnomecompat/screen0/options/command_terminal
```

to `gnome-terminal --maximize`

[image]

Comment: That does not seem to work. :-/

Comment: @queueoverflow: Without further information, I assumed you are using natty with unity. So please, elaborate a little bit about your system.

Comment: `/desktop/gnome/applications/terminal/exec` is the key that helps on my computer.

Comment: does not work for me either on ubuntu 14.04 with unity

Comment: Alternatively, open whatever keyboard shortcuts manager your native OS has. For instance, Ubuntu MATE has a `keyboard shortcuts` desktop app. There, you should be able to either reassign the existing `terminal` shortcut, or add a custom option which you could name `maximized terminal`, and supply the command `<your native terminal app> --maximized`. For instance, I did `mate-terminal --maximized`.

Answer (score 13):

Just as an alternative (maybe when you are working on another computer for a short time), after the window is open, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to the open the window's context menu and <kbd>X</kbd> to maximize. Similarly <kbd>N</kbd> to minimize and <kbd>C</kbd> to close. Works for all other applications too.

This combination is also the default for Microsoft Windows OS.

Comment: I prefer, in the order, Alt-F10, Alt-F9 and Alt-F4, bypassing the window menu :)

Comment: I too used to :). However, Alt is on the bottom line of keys and the functions are on the top, which kinda makes the adjacent duo easier to use. Plus X, C and N are also close by :)

Comment: I have set Alt+X to open my terminal, so Open + Maximize is very fast.

Comment: Doesn't work in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The window context menu doesn't seem to accept shortcuts like X or N or C.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this works for Gnome2 on Ubuntu 11.04, but it does for me on Ubuntu 12.04.

- Open a Terminal
- Select `Profile Preferences` from the `Edit` Menu.
- Tick `Use custom default terminal size` and enter a default size that is **too large** for the screen e.g. 240 columns and 100 rows.

Click close then open a new Terminal by clicking the icon OR pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, the new terminal window should be maximised.

This answer is based upon advice I was given here:
[How to make terminal start maximized?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138860/how-to-make-terminal-start-maximized)

Answer (score 5):

Just go to edit keyboard shortcuts in "Keyboard"
Then put the command `gnome-terminal --maximize` to the new custom shortcut
and set it to launch with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
(click reassign when the dialog box pops up.)

Comment: click disabled to set it to launch with Ctrl + Alt + T

Comment: this is the best one

Answer (score 1):

I am a linux newbe and am happy for your question. I did a simple tweak to my system and it worked. I see linux uses a lot of - what in my programming knowledge is referred to as persistence - which is the ability to save the state of an object.

So in order to accomplish your goal, when you open a terminal either from the application menu or by combining <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, just make sure before you close it, it's maximized, that will guarantee you that when you open again it will be maximized.

It's simple to me and workable.

Answer (score 0):

In new ubuntu 20.04 LTS you can press `Super + Up Arrow Key` (super is windows logo key) to maximize the terminal window, Similarly `Super + Down Arrow Key` to small size the terminal. To minimize `Super + H`